# How many SQL Queries will be executed in the database through this EF

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework, linq

I have the following and want to know how many queries will be executed in the DB through this EF?

```
private static dbContext dbc = new ProfileDBC();

private static IQueryable<Profile> GetProfile()
{
  return dbc.Profiles;
}


private static IQueryable<Purchase> GetPurchases()
{
  return from a in dbc.Amount
            where a.IsPurchased
            select a;
}

static void Main (string[] args)
{
   var result = (from p in GetProfile()
                  join pa in GetPurchases()
                  on p.ID equals pa.ID
                  group p.total by pa into r
                  select new { r.name, totalpurchase = r.Sum( p=> p)});.ToList(); }
}
```

}

Comment: Likely 1 query... why don't you check?

Comment: @TheGeneral: Thank you, I thought too but want to confirm

Comment: @TheGeneral: I am new, how do I check pls?

Comment: The question should likely be, How do I debug and profile a <insert database here>

Comment: the most reliable way would be something like sql server profiler, so you can see what the *server* sees

Comment: @Learner what verison of the EF are you using? EF have internal logger which logs queries so you need to enable/set correct level. But the most precise way would be to use db profiler.

Comment: @Learner do you have SQL Server Profiler? that's a great way to check the actual queries

Comment: @Vland: Profilers are outdated and decommisioned?

Comment: @Learner https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mkGoK8X0X3o take a look at this to understand what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be one query, after you've solved the compiler error:

```
Sum( p=> p)});.ToList();
```

If you want to fetch items with their sub-items, like Schools with their Students, Customers with their Orders, or Profiles with their Purchases, consider a GroupJoin instead of a `Join` followed by a `GroupBy`. The nice thing is that you will also get the Profiles that have no Purchases:

```
var profilesWithTheirPurchases = dbContext.Profiles.GroupJoin(dbContext.Purchases,

    // parameter KeySelector: compare primary and foreign key:
    profile => profile.Id,           // from every Profile take the Id
    purchase => purchase.ProfileId,  // from every Purchase take the ProfileId

    // parameter resultSelector: take every Profile with its zero or more Purchases
    // to make one new
    (profile, purchasesOfThisProfile) => new
    {
         Name = profile.Name,
         TotalPurchases = purchasesOfThisId.Select(purchase => purchase.Amount)
                                           .Sum(),
    });
```

Comment: i dont understand much technical things lol but you took so much effort to write down, I read, helpful....so a tick for you :) :) Thank you :)